# How to sign a Project using TFS Authenticode Code Signing with maximum security

Tags: tfs, signing

We have been asked to sign various projects in Visual Studio using a Verisign Certificate. It is not as simple as going to Properties | Signing and Choosing the strong name key file, as they do not want to include the certificate in the code. We somehow need to make the project build on our Build server where the certificate resides. Can you help point us in the right direction please. I believe the aim is to ensure that when built it is completely trustworthy without the developers ever gaining access to the Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

A better trick is to use two certificates / keys. One is for development, the other is the official one: the official one is accessible only to the user account running the release build.
A signing key can be stored in version control, and use a special mapping for the release build definition that gets the official key instead of the developers'. This is done by cloaking the single SNK file and mapping the good one on the same physical place (see [Workspaces: Mapping files instead of folders](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2008/06/19/workspaces-mapping-files-instead-of-folders.aspx)), something like

```
tf workfold /cloak $/MyProject/keys/mykey.snk
tf workfold /map $/MySecureProject/keys/mykey.snk C:\workdir\MyProject\keys\mykey.snk
```

Comment: Hi Giulio, thank you for your response. I am really sorry to sound nooby but if you could give me some more detail - i.e. any help topics - instructions? 
Also I wondered if you could elaborate on the final sentence specifically the Cloaking of the SNK. Thanks in advance